# How to zip multiple folders in a directory separately

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, 7-zip

There are multiple folders in a directory which I want to zip individually with original `FolderName.zip` and after they are zipped delete the original folders. There are other zipped folders already zipped in that directory which I want to keep as is. The tool I'm using to zip files is 7z as it was previously used to zipp manually. Following is the code I'm trying to run as batch file but it is failing just by blank screen

```
@ECHO OFF

SET SrcDir=G:\Backup\IPE\DAT
SET DestDir=G:\Backup\IPE\DAT\folderName.zip
IF NOT EXIST "%DestDir%" MD "%DestDir%"

ECHO.

ECHO Compressing files and folders in G:\Backup\IPE\DAT\ drive 
ECHO.

ECHO Compressing files and folders in G:\Backup\IPE\DAT\ drive and then delete original folders
ECHO.
FOR %%A IN ("%SrcDir%\*.*") DO 7za a -tzip "%DestDir%\%%~NA.zip" "%%~A" -mx5 && DEL /Q /F "%%~A"
ECHO.
PAUSE
```

Comment: FYI, `7z.exe` already has a `-sdel` option designed specifically to delete files after compression, _(essentially making it a 'move to archive' switch)_. BTW, `Del` does not have the ability to Remove Directories, for that you'd need to use the `RD` command.